# Trouble with C functions, specifically in calculation

Tags: c, function

```
// 6.1 Brain Teaser

#include <stdio.h>

int pills,weight;
float bottlenumber;

void load ()
{
     printf("Enter the number of pills: ");
     scanf("%d", &pills);
     printf("Enter the weight of your pills: ");
     scanf("%d", &weight);
}

void calc ()
{
     bottlenumber = (weight - 210) / (float)0.1;
}

void print()
{
     printf("The bottle number is %.f!", bottlenumber);
}

void main()
{
    load();
    calc();
    print();
}
```

The user is suppose to enter 211.3. The answer then is suppose to be 13 but instead I get 10. I think it has to do with float aspect and the calculation part.

Comment: there are only two preferred and one optional formats for the main() function declaration.   1) int main( void )  2) int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) and optionally 3) int main()   Note that all valid forms of the main function declaration have return type of 'int'   Suggest always enable all warnings when compiling (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  Then the compiler would have told you about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weight` is an `int`, not a `float`, and you're reading it in a as an `int`, so if the user enters 211.3 then `weight` contains 211.

If you expect `weight` to be a float then you should declare it as such and read it in as such.

```
float weight;

...

printf("Enter the weight of your pills: ");
scanf("%f", &weight);
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much. It's a brain teaser problem in the Cracking the Coding Interview that I took to write a program for it (6.1 specifically).

Answer (score 0):

this line is the problem:

```
bottlenumber = (weight - 210) / (float)0.1;
```

remember, the value entered for weight is 3.

so 3 - 210 = -207

next divide -207 by 0.1  which = -2070

I suspect the line should be written somewhat differently